# POST Submission not working + FASTCGI

Tags: php, post, fastcgi

I am having issue when I do simple form submission using post action. I am getting 504 Gateway time out error
Max_execution_time is set to 120 and we are using fast-cgi
$_POST array is blank. Can you please help me in resolving this issue.
When I make form submission as GET it works.

Comment: Are you posting files? If so it could be taking longer than your php max_execution_time(set in php.ini file) to transfer the files.

Comment: I am not posting any files. It is just a simple form which takes in name.